# how to make app turn off notification from pushwoosh?

Tags: cordova, pushwoosh

I using pushwoosh to send the push notification to my app and I would like to add some feature to check that if user is turn off "Revicieve Notification" on their devices, the push notification that I sent from pushwoosh will not fire or alert to those devices.

PS. I use cordova.

Thank you.

Comment: platform? do you mean that the user chooses from your app if he want's to turn off the notifications? or you mean on iOS if the user turn off the notifications on settings?

Comment: on iOS and android, my mean is if the user choose to turn off the notification on my app. it will not alert when I send the push notification fro pushwoosh.

Answer (score 2):

I've just gone through this minutes ago, solved with this:

```
            pushNotification.unregisterDevice(
                function (token) {
                    console.log("unregisterDevice, token: " + token);
                    //alert("unregisterDevice, token: " + token);
                },

                function (status) {
                    console.warn("registerDevice failed, status:" + status);
                    //alert("registerDevice failed, status:" + status);
                }
            );
```

We use localstorage to save settings, so in our case:

```
            var storage = window.localStorage;

            if (storage.getItem('pushNotification') == 'true') {
                console.log('Pusnotifications ON');

                //register for push notifications
                pushNotification.registerDevice(
                    function (token) {
                        console.log('registerDevice, token: ' + token);
                        //alert('registerDevice, token: ' + token);
                        //callback when pushwoosh is ready
                        onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(token);
                    },
                    function (status) {
                        //alert("registerDevice failed to register, status: " + status);
                        console.warn(JSON.stringify(["registerDevice failed to register, status: ", status]));
                    }
                );        


            } else if (storage.getItem('pushNotification') == 'false') {
                console.log('Pusnotifications OFF');

                //unregister for push notifications
                pushNotification.unregisterDevice(
                    function (token) {
                        console.log("unregisterDevice, token: " + token);
                        //alert("unregisterDevice, token: " + token);
                    },

                    function (status) {
                        console.warn("registerDevice failed, status:" + status);
                        //alert("registerDevice failed, status:" + status);
                    }
                );        
            }
```

As you might just figured out, this goes in '**PushwooshAndroid.js**'. I've not done this in iOS yet, but expect it to be the same.

Hope this helps you!
FG

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova take a look on:
**iOS**: *getRemoteNotificationStatus* function in Pushwoosh plugin.
Check "enabled" key there.
**Android**: You may consider user registered unless you call "unregisterDevice" function. As there is no API for Android to check push registration status. You can vote up here for this feature: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38482